# How to detect if it is an AJAX request in WordPress?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Is there anyway to detect if the current server operation is currently an AJAX request in WordPress?

For example:

```
is_ajax()
```

Comment: if *what* is currently an ajax request? "it" can mean anything. and where/why do you need to check this?

Comment: It sounds like, by the phrasing of your question, that you're not entirely sure what AJAX is. I suggest looking at this: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Comment: [This article](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) doesn't make a check for it, so perhaps you don't need to? If you are using jQuery, you can always add a `?ajax=1` when you call the server, if you wish.

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-Intelligently

Comment: Folks, I think what is being asked is "is this server request as a result of a page request or an AJAX request". Perfectly reasonable question, though I agree it could have a bit more detail. Nevertheless, I'll +1 since I've not seen it here before, and to discourage hasty downvoting.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Update: since WordPress 4.7.0 you can call a function [wp_doing_ajax()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_doing_ajax/). This is preferable because plugins that "do Ajax" differently can filter to turn a "false" into a "true".

---

Original answer:

If you're using Ajax [as recommended in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins), then you can test for the `DOING_AJAX` constant:

```
if (defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX) { /* it's an Ajax call */ }
```

Comment: +1 for being **WordPress** specific. I forgot he mentioned he was using **WP**. This would be the preferred way in that environment.

Comment: It's not mentioned in that link. I searched myself for this yesterday for this question - are there actually WP docs on this, do you know?

Comment: It's not in the docs (yet -- but it's a wiki, so you can add it!), but it's in the code. There's no better docs than the code. AJAX done the "codex" way uses wp-admin/admin-ajax.php, and if you look at the top of that file, you'll see DOING_AJAX defined.

Comment: you can see it referenced in a if statement on this page https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init

Answer (score 43):

**WordPress 4.7** has introduced an easy way to check for AJAX requests, so I thought I would add to this older question.

```
wp_doing_ajax()
```

From the [Developer Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_doing_ajax/):

- Description: Determines whether the current request is a WordPress Ajax request.
- Return: (bool) True if it's a WordPress Ajax request, false otherwise.

It is essentially a wrapper for DOING_AJAX.

Answer (score 16):

To see if the current request is an **AJAX** request sent from a js library ( like **jQuery** ), you could try something like this:

```
if( ! empty( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH' ] ) &&
      strtolower( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH' ]) == 'xmlhttprequest' ) {
    //This is an ajax request.
}
```

Comment: +1 for a shorter version, and for me learning something today.

Comment: HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH does not appears in $_SERVER in Wordpress.

Comment: @vee, `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` isn't set by WordPress. It gets populated if the originator of the request passes the headers for it.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old thread, but there is an issue with the accepted answer,

Checking for the defined DOING_AJAX constant will always be true, if the request is to the admin-ajax.php file. (https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php#L16)

Sometimes admin-ajax.php hooks aren't used for AJAX request, just a simple endpoint (Paypal IPN for example).

The correct way is what Ian and Spencer have mentioned.

```
if( ! empty( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH' ] ) &&
      strtolower( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH' ]) == 'xmlhttprequest' ) {
    //This is an ajax request.
}
```

(would have commented... but no rep)

Comment: Thanks for this - specifically this allowed me to not run functions when Woocommerce was making AJAX calls to modify a persons cart.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if WordPress has a function for this but it can be done by creating a simple one yourself.

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
{
    // Is AJAX request
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: Although !empty probably isn't needed as it doesn't return an error.

Comment: Actually, `isset` is not needed. `empty` checks whether or not the variable exists already.

Comment: @SpencerCameron - wouldn't `empty` without `isset` raise a PHP warning if this element doesn't exist?

Comment: I thought the first thing empty() checks is isset()? so isset() would make empty() redundant.

Comment: I know that they would both work on their own but surely the first thing empty() does is check isset()?

Comment: @IanBrindley, `empty` will also check whether or not the variable has a value assigned to it in addition to being **set**. Either one would work in this case. Why evaluate the second half of the logical expression if the variable is set but empty? That's my thinking on the subject. Really, this is splitting hairs, but I prefer using `empty`.

Comment: @SpencerCameron, fair point. Getting to point of splitting hairs for me is a great way to learn :-). Cheers all.

Answer (score 4):

```
if ( ! function_exists('is_ajax') ) {
    function is_ajax() {
        return defined( 'DOING_AJAX' );
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be beneficial to accompany the code with some commentary.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer the `wp_doing_ajax()`, but here is another example that should do it.

```
if( true === strpos( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' ) ) {
    // is doing ajax
}
```