# Getting XML Data from Ajax Response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xml, wordpress

I'm getting the following XML response back from a Wordpress AJAX request and having trouble extracting the data. I think it's because it's being parsed as CDATA, but I can't see why.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wp_ajax>
   <response action="mz_mindbody_ajax_add_to_class_0">
      <object id="0" position="1">
     <response_data><![CDATA[error]]></response_data>
     <supplemental>
        <classID><![CDATA[2237]]></classID>
        <message><![CDATA[Error in add to class (2237)]]></message>
     </supplemental>
      </object>
   </response>
</wp_ajax>
```

This is the php to handle the AJAX call:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var my_parameters = {"ajaxurl":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<?php

// Ajax Handler
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_ajax_handler', 'my_ajax_handler' );
function my_ajax_handler() {
    // Get the Post ID from the URL
    $classID = $_REQUEST['classID'];

    // Instantiate WP_Ajax_Response
    $response = new WP_Ajax_Response;

    if( wp_verify_nonce( $_REQUEST['nonce'], 'nonce-name' . $classID )){
    //Do something here

    $response->add( array(
        'data'  => 'success',
        'supplemental' => array(
        'classID' => 'did it',
        'message' => 'Class ID goes here', // ideally want to show $classID
        ),
     ) );
    } else {
    // Build the response if an error occurred
    $response->add( array(
        'data'  => 'error',
        'supplemental' => array(
        'classID' => 'nothing to see here',
        'message' => 'Error in add to class',
        ),
    ) );
    }
    // Whatever the outcome, send the Response back
    $response->send();

    // Always exit when doing Ajax
    exit();
}
//End Ajax
```

This is the jQuery code:

```
(function($){
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $( '.my_class' ).click( function( e ) {
        var link = this;
        var id   = $( link ).attr( 'data-id' );
        var nonce = $( link ).attr( 'data-nonce' );

        // This is what we are sending the server
        var data = {
            action: 'my_function',
            classID: id,
            nonce: nonce
        }
        // Change text of link
        $( link ).text( 'DOING IT' );

        // Post to the server
        $.post( my_parameters.ajaxurl, data, function( data ) {
            // Parse the XML response with jQuery
            // Get the Status
            console.log(data); //the XML data posted above
            var status = $( data ).find( 'response_data' ).text();
            // Get the Message
            var message = $( data ).find( 'supplemental message' ).text();
            // If we are successful, add the success message and remove the link
            console.log(status); // empty string
            if( status == 'success' ) {
            $( link ).parent().after( '<p><strong>' + message + '</strong></p>').remove();
            } else {
            // An error occurred, alert an error message
            alert( message );
            }
        });
        // Prevent the default behavior for the link
        e.preventDefault();
        });
    }); 
})(jQuery);
```

In the tutorial I'm following the `$response->add()` calls are within a function. Is the fact that mine *aren't* what's causing the problem here?

Wait - I have misrepresented the `data` "object", which may be part of (or all of) the problem. The entire data "object" is actually a *string*, which in the console looks like:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var mz_mbo_params = {"ajaxurl":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?><wp_ajax><response action='mz_mindbody_ajax_add_to_class_0'><object id='0' position='1'><response_data><![CDATA[error]]></response_data><supplemental><classID><![CDATA[nothing to see here]]></classID><message><![CDATA[Error in add to class]]></message></supplemental></object></response></wp_ajax>
```

Comment: yea. i think so. the XML I posted is the result of the `console.log(data);` in the $.post callback you can see above. That anonymous function is the $.post callback, right?

Answer (score 1):

Update

Given response `data` `string` ; Note, not certain about quotations of actual raw `string` returned at `data`

```
var data = "<script type='text/javascript'>/* <![CDATA[ */var mz_mbo_params = {\"ajaxurl\":\"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php\"};/* ]]> */</script><?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?><wp_ajax><response action='mz_mindbody_ajax_add_to_class_0'><object id='0' position='1'><response_data><![CDATA[error]]></response_data><supplemental<classID><![CDATA[nothing to see here]]></classID><message><![CDATA[Error in add to class]]></message></supplemental></object></response></wp_ajax>";
```

try utilizing [jQuery.parseHTML()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parseHTML)

```
var xml = $.parseHTML(data, document, false)[1]; // remove `script` element
// do stuff
$(xml).find("message");
```

---

Try utilizing [$.parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parseXML) with `data` argument , calling [jQuery()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/) with `documentElement` of parsed `xml` `document` argument

```
// response `data` from `$.post()` callback
var xmlDocument = $.parseXML(data); 
// `documentElememt` `<wp_ajax></wp_ajax>` of response `xml` `data`
var xml = $(xmlDocument.documentElement); 
var status = xml.find("response_data").text();
var message = xml.find("supplemental message").text();
console.log(status); // empty string
if ( status == "success" ) {
   $( link )
   .parent()
   .after("<p><strong>" + message + "</strong></p>").remove();
} else {
   // An error occurred, alert an error message
   alert( message );
}
```

```js
var data = '<wp_ajax><response action="mz_mindbody_ajax_add_to_class_0"><object id="0" position="1"><response_data><![CDATA[error]]></response_data><supplemental><classID><![CDATA[2237]]></classID><message><![CDATA[Error in add to class (2237)]]></message></supplemental></object></response></wp_ajax>'
var xmlDocument = $.parseXML(data);
var xml = $(xmlDocument.documentElement);
var status = xml.find("response_data").text();
var message = xml.find("supplemental message").text();
console.log(status); // empty string
if ( status == "success" ) {
   $( link )
   .parent()
   .after("<p><strong>" + message + "</strong></p>").remove();
} else {
   // An error occurred, alert an error message
   alert( message );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah. This is illuminating. I have misrepresented my `data` object. When I run your code with the hard-coded data it works, but the data I'm actually returning contains more details at the top - which I'm added to the question: `<script type='...` + `/* <![CDATA[ */...`+`var mz_mbo_params = {"ajaxurl"`+`<?xml version='1.0' ` and THEN the wp_ajax stuff!

Comment: @MikeiLL Is `data` returned as `html` `string` , `xml` `string` , or `object` _"data object"_ ?

Comment: Can include returned raw text `string` at post, including quotation marks, without formatting ? , how returned at `console.log(data)` - before any processing ? If possible, can add `textStatus, jqxhr` to `$.post()` callback,  `console.log(jqxhr.responseText)` ?

Comment: When I add `textStatus, jqxhr` as parameters to the $.post callback and `console.log(jqxhr.responseText)` it looks the same in the console as data. Actually `jqxhr.responseText == data` is `true`.

Comment: Yes. Can include actual raw `string` at original post,  without formatting as `html` ? , instead of `<script type='text/javascript'>` and remainder of `string` wrapped in `code` block ? including `'`, or `""` around `jqxhr.responseText` ? An alternative approach would be to utilize `$.parseHTML(data, document, false)[1]` to extract `xml` from returned data; though, requires `string` to try at stacksnippets . See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/

Comment: 1. Do you mean my actual post in SO? I'm having trouble posting it in any other way. (The output I copy from the last code snippet above looks the same as console.log when pasted into a text editor.)

Comment: Yes. Though, actual _string_ , without selecting and wrapping with "{}" , `code` within SO editor. Or, select, copy, paste "Paste as plain text" `Ctrl+Shift+V` - the actual response text, _without_ `code` formatting , including surrounding quotation marks. See updated post at `var data = "<script type='text/javascript'>..` SO runs jquery 1.7.1, which does not include `$.parseHTML` , or could try running `data` string at `console.log()` - stacksnippets requires valid string to utilize `$.parseHTML()`

Comment: Narrowing in on it! `$(xml).find( 'supplemental message' );` is and `object Object`.

Comment: the keys of the object are: `["length", "prevObject", "context", "selector"]`. Still grasping around in the dark a bit here.

Comment: Yes, "keys" appear to be jQuery "array-like" object ? Can post returned `string` "data" at original post ? Are keys retrieved utilizing `$.parseXML` or `$.parseHTML` ?

Comment: When you say "running `data` string at `console.log()`" do you mean simply, `console.log(data)`? That's exactly what I've pasted above. Do you mean to paste what I take from the console without pasting the  `<script type='text/javascript'>` at the beginning? `Ctrl+Shift+V` doesn't do anything in the SO editor as far as I can tell, nor do any of the variations I've tried, aside from `Cmd+V` (on `OSX`). I'm also not sure where you mean to put quotes around `jqxhr.responseText`. Sorry if I'm being dense here.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is of much use. I tried pasting what seems to be the `data` string (as returned by `console.log()`) into the codesnippet js window, but it contains `'` AND `"` so won't work of course. When I run `data = data.substring(208);`, removing the undesired elements from the string, utilizing `$.parseXML`, I get the result I want, but this can't be the proper way to handle it. Why is my php code returning a string in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem you've got with your wordpress configuration. Fix the configuration that results in pre-pending XML-RPC responses with the ajax script tag. It breaks the response.

Most likely you've registered that on some hook that is too generic or your hooked function doesn't filter out AJAX calls.

- [Is Ajax in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14348470/367456)