# is_ajax is deprecated since version 6.1.0

Tags: wordpress

I am facing this error on my WordPress website:

```
Deprecated: is_ajax is deprecated since version 6.1.0! Use wp_doing_ajax instead. in /home/u523973308/domains/celebd.in/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5211
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Ajax in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14349862/15040627)

Comment: In the error message also mentioned you could use`wp_doing_ajax` instead!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and I fixed it by adding these lines in 'wp-config.php' file.

Insert BEFORE this line **That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging.**

```
// Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

// Disable display of errors and warnings 
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
error_reporting(0);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

GOTO the wp-config.php
if your

> define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

Change it

> define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );